# updating html table row with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a jquery script that returns the number of rows in a table, then sets that number inside a `<td>` tag.

```
<tr>
 <td id = "jquery">

 </td>
 <td>
  <%= f.text_field :data1 %>
 </td>
 <td>
  <%= f.text_field :data2 %>
 </td>
  <td>
  <%= f.text_field :data3 %>
 </td>
</tr>
<script>
    var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length
    $("#jquery").html(rowCount);    
</script>
```

This script works but when I render this view again to add another row to myTable, it only updates the first row instead of the next row with `rowCount`.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You want to display the rowcount in td of all the rows?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do when you say "it only updates the first row", doing what? Adding a new row with which code?

Comment: Yes. But I would like the previous rowcount to be in the previous row. The current row count in the most current row.

Comment: you are using an id for the selector which will only ever select that element

Comment: Add a small example of what result you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the same row again so there will be 2 tr with same id as jquery in this case 
it selects only the first element with the given ID.

So instead of id provide class="jquery" and then run the script:

```
 <td class= "jquery">
```

and

```
<script>
   $('tr').each(function(){
     var index= $('table').children('tr').index($(this))
     var position= index+1;
     $(this).children('td').first().html(position);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This is correct. IDs should only appear once on a page and jQuery will only grab the first one that it finds.

Comment: That updates all rows with the current `rowcount`.  I need to update keep the previous rows with the old `rowcount`.

Comment: You mean first rows td will display 1, second rows td will display 2 and so on?

Comment: The problem is you can't update something that's static. In your case jQuery id remains still always. So  $(".jquery").html(rowCount); will always update all of them (assuming you're cloning the row). You need a new name for every single td "jquery" element.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to see my error =/.  @Farhan, yep that is what I need.

Comment: your code is a little bit off, you should use `$(this).parent("table")` instead of `$('table')` as it will use whatever last table it finds which might not be the one that the tr is in.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of the current code you have that only sets the first element of the id `jquery`.

if you want each first td to have total count:

```
var count = $("#mytable tr").length;
$("#mytable tr > td:first-child").html( count );
```

each first td has the row index number

```
$("#mytable tr").each(function(){
   $(this).children("td").first().html( $(this).index() );
});
```

there might be a shorter chain for the above but i can't think of one at the moment.
if you want a non-zero starting index just use `.index()+1`.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nVpHG/)

Comment: Looks way better solution and it doesn't need to name td's with an id.

Comment: yea but hes counting the rows, i thought he was counting tds so this is wrong, editing to make right

Comment: @GVIPProgrammer but are you wanting the total count or its like level count, like the first tr should have 1, second tr should have 2?

Comment: Exactly. a level count.  I apologize if I was not descriptive enough.

Comment: I have no doubt you have the correct answer, but it seems to be incrementing by 2's on my end.  2, 4, 6, 8, etc...

Comment: look at the fiddle thats linked in my answer, thats how it should look, you might have it some weird way